# How can I add my basic python code into a gui

Tags: python, user-interface

I am a complete beginner and would like if someone could put my altered stretch of code provided below into a simple gui. I have no idea how to do it and learn well from seeing results. So once I've seen the code I will most likely understand how it works and what I've been doing wrong.

```
import time

print("Please enter the password.")
Pass = input("Password: ")

if Pass==("Economics"): 
    print("Password Correct, now entering program!"); 
    print("Gathering Information..."); time.sleep(0.5);
    print("Fetching answers..."); 
else:
    print("Incorrect login credentials, self destructing in 5")
time.sleep(1.0);
print("4");
time.sleep(1.0);
print("3");
time.sleep(1.0)
print("2");
time.sleep(1.0);
print("1")
time.sleep(1.0);
print("Joking! Try to login again.")

print("Please enter the password.")
Pass = input("Password: ")

if Pass==("Economics"): 
    print("Your password is correct, you can now progress to the quiz"); 
    print("Gathering Information..."); time.sleep(0.5);
```

Comment: You might want to look at [the `tkinter` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html). Additionally, [this resource](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) may be more introductory.

Comment: I'm afraid taking a script written for the console and modifying it to run as a GUI application isn't quite as simple taking `script` and wrapping it with `GUI(script)`. Your program will need an entirely different architecture. You'll use OOP (object oriented programming) to define the GUI elements, event-driven programming to take and respond to user input, libraries to abstract away the actual hairy implementation of displaying pixels in a cross platform way...the difference between the two isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make a GUI for a python code, I suggest using the library "PyQt" it's a very powerful and simple library for GUI implementations for C++/Python. you will need to download "Qt Designer" as well. It's an IDE (similar to eclipse if you will) for developing the GUI using PyQt.  So to sum up you need:

1. Python.
2. PyQt library.
3. Qt Designer.

If you are using windows you can download  the last 2 items as a package from here: [Qt Designer + PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)

choose from the binary package for windows, based on your python verion Py2.7/3 and based on your windows version 64 vs 32 bit.

After that follow this tutorial on how to make a GUI HelloWorld app using Python and PyQt.

[Python GUI tutorial using PyQt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcX2FsPlVeI)